# Regex to validate full name

Tags: regex

Full name can be 1 to 3 words separated by a space, consisting of the following:

- FirstName (allow letters and a hyphen character `-`),
- MiddleName (allow letters only) and
- LastName (allow letters and a hyphen character `-`)

NOTE: the full name should not exceed 50 characters.

Valid inputs:
`Abc`
`Abc-abc abc`
`Abc-abc abc abc-abc`
`abc abc abc`

Invalid inputs:
`abc abc-abc abc`
`abc qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjkllz` (exceeded 50 characters)

My initial regex was as follows:
`^([a-zA-Z\-]{1,50}|[a-zA-Z\-]+\s{1}[a-zA-Z\-]+|[a-zA-Z\-]+\s{1}[a-zA-Z]+\s{1}[a-zA-Z\-]+)$`

I was not able to add length check for 2 and 3 words.

Comment: If you're actually planning to validate names, I would suggest you don't - just check character length? Poor Shaquille O'Neal will never be able to enter his name. Same with Elon's son X Æ A-12.

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: yes, you are right.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If supported, you could use a positive lookahead to check if the string does not contain 51 characters.

Use an optional group inside an optional group to match the second and the last name, preventing the second name containing a `-`

You don't have to escape the hyphen at the end of the character class.

```
^(?!.{51})[a-zA-Z-]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z-]+)?)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uq38Fp/1)